# Does re-use of file pointers cause a memory leak?

Tags: c++, file-io, memory-leaks, fopen, fclose

It's been several years since I've dealt with C++, so bear with me...

I have a memory leak in my program which causes a run-time error.  Could this be causing the error?

I have a global variable `FILE *fp;`

In a callback funciton, I have:

```
fp = fopen(filen,"w");
// do some writing
fclose(fp);
```

This process is repeated several times with the same pointer (fp).  Is using the same file pointer a problem?  Will fclose() automatically free up memory for me, or do I need to delete it manually?  Are there any limitations that might cause a run-time error if I'm writing large quantities of text?

Thanks!

Comment: as you said its a global, i suspect you are having problem with uninitialized variable. always set the FILE to `NULL` in case you check `if(fp != NULL)` in the code somewhere when you actually use the pointer for read/write. also, it might be that the file open failed and returned `NULL` when you try to use this pointer it will cause crash too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This approach won't cause any memory leaks so long as the `fopen` is always followed by a `fclose` before the next`fopen` call.

However if this is indeed what's happening I would question the need for a global variable.  It's much safer overall to make this a local and pass it around to the functions which need to output information.

Comment: Thanks.  The program is a plugin, so I don't know if I can pass extra arguments to the callback. However, the file will stay open through several hundred iterations of the callback before closing, so I can't just make it a local variable.

Comment: @Jeff: Almost every function that takes a callback also takes a `void*` pointer, the so-called "user data" which is passed back to your function. Does your API also do so?

Comment: For that matter, it's much safer overall to use iostreams.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, `fclose` releases all resources associated with the `FILE *`. As a rule of thumb, only use `free` on what was allocated with `malloc`, and only use `delete` on what was allocated with `new`.

And you're never "reusing" the same pointer: a call to `fopen` will return a new `FILE *`.

By the way, since you're doing C++, consider looking into `fstream`. It'll handle the resource management for you.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're doing things exactly correctly -- `fclose` should reverse whatever `fopen` does, including freeing any resources it might allocate.

Answer (score 0):

Multiple threads hitting the same global could cause an issue that would appear after one of the threads closed the file.

Opening the file a subsequent time and changing the file pointer wouldn't be seen when it happened.

Closing the file would only close 1 of the created file handles leaving a file handle leak and any further writes to the file would fail and a subsequent close file on the same handle trying to close it a second time would likely crash if it didn't already happen writing to the file.